# Adding CSS drop shadow to all sides of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is advice for a beginner, please do not tell me why I shouldn't use tables.

How do I add a drop shadow to all edges of my table *using CSS*? also where should I put it? and how do I link it to the table?

```
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS `box-shadow` property.

```
box-shadow: 8px 5px 5px 0px #aaa;
```

If you are not comfortable with CSS yet then there are a few websites that do it for you. [This one](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/) came up as the first result in Google.

So, everything together would look something like this:

```
<style>
  table {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
  }
</style>
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```